# Which memory profiler can help in web as well as non web .NET apps? Dotmemory.. Or Red Gate ANTS Or Newrelic or something else

Tags: .net

Want to get a tool which can help identify memory leaks in web applications as well as non-web like Windows services.

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time on nothing, are you sure your application is leaking? For example an asp.net app growing in memory over time doesn't necessarily indicate a leak (iis isntanciates the CLR with parameters indicating not to release memory unless it is under memory pressure)

Comment: For a free solution use WinDbg/SOS.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau
The only way to know if your application is leaking or not is using profiler tool

Answer (score 1):

Dot memory will do what you need from jetbrains. http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/